# Cassandra rpc timeout occurring during heavy writes and deletes

Tags: timeout, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm using cassandra 2.0, and I have created a column family that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_id_timestamp_index (
  user_id int,
  timestamp text,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, timestamp)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='NONE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

I've written over 2 million rows to this table without any issues, and I perform numerous deletes as well.

The problem arises after about 10k deletes or so in rapid succession, and I start encountering numerous rpc_timeouts.  A simple "delete from user_id_timestamp_index where user_id = 5 AND timestamp = '12345'" via cqlsh fails during this period.

Things I've noticed and tried:

1. During rpc timeouts, Load Average on 2 nodes (out of 5) shoot up to about 50.
2. Compaction is done almost every 5 minutes during these load-intensive writes and deletes.
3. During rpc_timeouts, tpstats shows pending mutation stages:
   MutationStage                    64 (active)      395 (pending)      48182373 (completed)        0                 0
4. Timeouts tend to occur when memtable data size exceeds 3 mb for this CF.
5. After I perform a nodetool flush, pending mutations goes to zero and rpc time disappears, until memtable size creeps up again to past 3 mb.

My question is, there a configuration I can tune?  For example, is the solution to simply force a memtable flush on this column family every 5 minutes? Lessen the write load on this table?  A way to have faster writes and reduce pending stages? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing GC pressure (which you can tell from the GCInspector lines in the log), you can reduce the amount of memory used by memtables by adjusting `memtable_total_space_in_mb` in `cassandra.yaml`.  You may also need to [reduce the key or row cache settings](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/cassandra/operations/ops_configuring_caches_c.html) instead or as well.